# Tkinter c.move text with degrees?

Tags: python, tkinter

In Tkinter, I need to be able to move text in a certain degrees, not to a new x and y coordinate. is there any way I could do this? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Are you trying to *rotate* the text?

Answer (score 1):

No, you cannot rotate text on a canvas.

From the canonical documentation:

> Individual items may be moved or scaled using widget commands described below, but they may not be rotated.

Comment: If you absolutely have to have rotated text, you can do it in a different language such as Perl or Ruby. But I wouldn't go this path if you don't have to. Also just a friendly reminder: please don't use Tkinter for game graphics, it's a GUI program, for game graphics use PyGame.